# Installing a package for a specific version of python in an existing environment with conda

Tags: conda

I have a following problem, I have an existing conda environment with a bunch of packages from conda_forge, and this environment uses python 3.10. Now, I want to add to this existing environment a package from the cascade channel. For now if I do `conda install -c cascade climextremes` I get

```
Specifications: 
  - climextremes -> python[version='2.7*|3.6.*|>=3.6,<3.70a0']

Your python: python[version='>3.9']
```

At the same time, I know that there is a version of that package which is compatible with python 3.10, because I once already have installed that package from the same channel to the same environment (the environment had to be installed on a different computer). I just don't remember and can't find from googling how exactly specify a python version while installing just one package into the existing environment.

Answer (score 0):

On anaconda.org, the maximum version of Python that `climextremes` is built for is version 3.6.  You can see this in the file name versioning: https://anaconda.org/cascade/climextremes/files.

However, it does appear to be built for Python up to 3.10 on PyPi.  It requires numpy, pandas, rpy2, and tzlocal.  So may want to install those with conda, then pip install the climextremes package.

```
conda activate my_env
conda install numpy pandas rpy2 tzlocal -y
pip install climextremes
```